# Как объединить два диапазона генерации?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как заполнить элемент типа string заглавными буквами и случайными цифрами вместе?

Первый (диапазон генерации заглавных букв)

```
с = (65) + rand() % 26
```

Второй (генерация чисел от -9 до 9)

```
с = (-9) + rand() % 18
```

Пробовал их банально сложить через плюс два диапазона, получается какой-то ужас..

Comment: Что вам нужно? Получать число, которое равномерно размазано по двум диапазонам? Но диапазоны у вас перекрываются!

Comment: @Harry, добавил в описании, необходимо заполнить элемент случайными заглавными буквами и цифрами

Comment: Так *цифрами* или *числами*? Цифры это символы 0, 1..., 9.

Comment: цифрами, извиняюсь

Comment: определите количество возможных значений (сумма двух диапазонов) и генерируйте рандом исходя из этого числа, а потом посредствам простого if-else (например если меньше 26) относите результат к нужному диапазону

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего не мучиться и сделать примерно так:

```
const char * ab = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string s;
for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    s = s + ab[rand()%strlen(ab)];
```